# Python... display positive even numbers up to...

Tags: python

Im new to python and although this following question seems easy I cant seem to get it right. After I put my input for n in the code and cant think of a way to get a formula that works.

This is the question:
Write a program that asks the user for a positive even integer input n, and the outputs the sum 2+4+6+8+...+n, the sum of all the positive even integers up to n.

thanks for any help!!!

Comment: Post your current code.

Answer (score 3):

Two tips, since this is an assignment and you haven't posted any code.

1. The `range` function can produce the list you want.  It takes 3 parameters, the start of the list, the stop (which is not included in the list), and the step.  Since you're counting every other number, your step is 2.
2. The `sum` function would be quite useful.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the result you are looking for is twice the sum of the integers in `[1, n/2]`, which evaluates to `(n/2)*(n/2 + 1)/2`. The formula you are looking for hence is `(n/2)*(n/2 + 1)`.

Comment: Which can be written as `n*(n+2)/4`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `n=8`. `range` gives you a list of the numbers you wish to add

```
>>> range(2, n+1,2)
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

and `sum` gives you a way to add up the entries in the list

```
>>> sum(range(2, n+1, 2))
20
```

It's possible to calculate the sum without adding all the individual numbers using this formula

```
>>> n*(n+2)/4
20
```

But you should probably show how to derive the formula if you intend to use that answer.

Here is a sketch for n=12, `A` represents 10 and `C` represents 12

```
22CCCCCCCCCCCC
4444AAAAAAAAAA
66666688888888
```

Looking at the top row, we see that this rectangle is `(n+2)` wide. And after a little thought you'll see that the height is `n/4`. The sum, is then just the product of those two terms.

A similar argument can work when `n` is not divisable by 4.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest, but will give incorrect answer for odd  or negative numbers:

```
n=int(raw_input('Enter a positive even integer:'))
print n*(n+2)/4
```

Gives correct answer for odd and negative numbers:

```
n=int(raw_input('Enter a positive even integer:')) >>1<<1
print n*(n+2)/4 if n>0 else 0
```

or

```
n=int(raw_input('Enter a positive even integer:'))
print sum(range(2, n+1, 2))
```

Comment: Im using 3.3 which is just input instead of raw_input, however I seem to get invalid syntax messages?